# Как исправить ошибку OverflowError: int too large to convert to float

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задание в котором следует исследовать ряд на сходимость
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Условие окончания цикла вычисления суммы принять в виде:
| un | <E або | un | > G где Е - малая величина для прерывания цикла вычисления суммы схождения ряда (е = 10-5 ... 10-20); G - величина для прерывания цикла вычисления суммы расхождения ряда (g = 102 ...
105).

и у меня есть некий скрипт:

```py
def task_series12():
    """check the series (variant 12) for convergence"""
    n = 1
    s = u = 2
    e = 1e-10  # g = 1e+5
    while abs(u) > e:  # abs(u)>g
        print(u)
        n += 1
        if n ** math.sqrt(n) == 0:
            break
        u = (math.factorial(n) * math.exp(n)) / (n ** math.sqrt(n))
        s += u
    else:
        print("Series converge to: ", s)  # "Maximum sum is:"
        return True
    print("Division by zero!")
    return False
```

но как итог выбивает ошибку **OverflowError: int too large to convert to float**

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Вызов `math.factorial(n), n > 170` порождает числа которые не могут быть переведены во `float`.

Чтобы это исправить, выразите член ряда `a(n + 1)` через `a(n)`. Вычисляйте их в цикле друг через друга. Так вы продвинетесь дальше.

Но далеко вы не уйдёте. Чтобы понять почему, печатайте значения `a(n)` и вспоминайте условие сходимости ряда.

Answer (score 1):

Зря вы игнорировали часть задания "G - величина для прерывания цикла вычисления суммы расхождения ряда". Вам надо проверять и эту часть. Ряд может как сходиться, так и расходиться.

Если вам нужно в цикле проверять несколько условий выхода, то лучше это делать так:

```
e = 1e-10
g = 1e+5
while True:
    if abs(u) < e:
        print('Ряд сошёлся')
        break
    if abs(u) > g:
        print('Ряд разошёлся')
        break
    # остальное тело цикла
```